# Compare files by name in two folders A and B and delete duplicates from folder A

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, file-system

I wrote [my very first Python program](https://superuser.com/a/1093749/32245) to answer a [Super User question](https://superuser.com/questions/1093727/is-there-a-way-to-remove-files-from-a-folder-that-are-in-another-folder). I'm wondering how the application can be rewritten to make it as [pythonic](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/writing/style/) as possible.

#### Unit test

```
import unittest
import os
import shutil
from DeleteDuplicateInFolderA import DeleteDuplicateInFolderA


class DeleteDuplicateInFolderATest(unittest.TestCase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DeleteDuplicateInFolderATest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._base_directory = r"c:\temp\test"
        self._path_A = self._base_directory + r"\A"
        self._path_B = self._base_directory + r"\B"

    def create_folder_and_create_some_files(self, path, filename_list):
        if os.path.exists(path):
            shutil.rmtree(path)
        os.makedirs(path)
        for filename in filename_list:
            open(os.path.join(path, filename), "w+").close()

    def setUp(self):
        # Create folders and files for testing
        self.create_folder_and_create_some_files(self._path_A, ["1.txt", "2.txt"])
        self.create_folder_and_create_some_files(self._path_B, ["2.txt", "3.txt"])

    def tearDown(self):
        for path in [self._path_A, self._path_B, self._base_directory]:
            if os.path.exists(path):
                shutil.rmtree(path)

    def test_duplicate_file_gets_deleted(self):
        # Arrange
        app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(self._path_A, self._path_B, is_dry_run=False)

        # Act
        app.delete_duplicates_in_folder_A()

        # Assert
        self.assertFalse(os.path.isfile(self._path_A + r"\2.txt"), "File 2.txt has not been deleted.")

    def test_duplicate_file_gets_not_deleted_in_mode_dryrun(self):
        # Arrange
        app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(self._path_A, self._path_B, is_dry_run=True)

        # Act
        app.delete_duplicates_in_folder_A()

        # Assert
        self.assertTrue(os.path.isfile(self._path_A + r"\2.txt"), "File 2.txt should not have been deleted in mode '--dryrun'")

def main():
    unittest.main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

#### Application

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os


class DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(object):
    """Given two paths A and B, the application determines which files are in
       path A which are also in path B and then deletes the duplicates from
       path A.

       If the "dry run" flag is set to 'false', files are deleted. Otherwise
       they are only displayed but not deleted.
    """

    def __init__(self, path_A, path_B, is_dry_run=True):
        self._path_A = path_A
        self._path_B = path_B
        self._is_dry_run = is_dry_run

    def get_filenames_in_folder(self, folder_path):
        only_files = []
        for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(folder_path):
            only_files.extend(filenames)
        return only_files

    def print_files(sel, heading, files):
        print(heading)
        if len(files) == 0:
            print("   none")
        else:
            for file in files:
                print("   {}".format(file))

    def delete_duplicates_in_folder_A(self):
        only_files_A = self.get_filenames_in_folder(self._path_A)
        only_files_B = self.get_filenames_in_folder(self._path_B)

        files_of_A_that_are_in_B = [file for file in only_files_A if file in only_files_B]

        self.print_files("Files in {}".format(self._path_A), only_files_A)
        self.print_files("Files in {}".format(self._path_B), only_files_B)

        if self._is_dry_run:
            self.print_files("These files would be deleted: ", [os.path.join(self._path_A, file) for file in files_of_A_that_are_in_B])
        else:
            print("Deleting files:")
            for filepath in [os.path.join(self._path_A, file) for file in files_of_A_that_are_in_B]:
                print("   {}".format(filepath))
                os.remove(filepath)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        is_dry_run_argument = sys.argv[3]
        if not is_dry_run_argument == "--dryrun":
            print("The 3rd argument must be '--dryrun' or nothing.")
        else:
            app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=True)
    else:
        app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=False)
    app.delete_duplicates_in_folder_A()
```

Comment: You made a little mistake.  It should be `print(...)`, not `println(...)` in your `if not is_dry_...` block.  Python, not JavaScript ;)

Comment: @zondo: Well spotted, thanks. I fixed it. That means my test suite sucks...

Comment: @Lernkurve, please remember it is CodeReview policy not to change your code once you've gotten feedback.

Comment: Is your intention for the comparison/deletion to work recursively in subdirectories? Have you tested the recursive comparison?

Comment: @200_success: No, there was no intention to compare recursively in subdirectories.

Comment: @user1717828: Thank you for letting me know! Note to self: [For an iterative review, is it okay to edit my own question to include revised code?](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1763/for-an-iterative-review-is-it-okay-to-edit-my-own-question-to-include-revised-c)

Comment: One other thing I haven't seen mentioned here is that there is no state, so a class is unecessary. Free functions would more clearly document the data flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure you use some tools to check your code (e.g. [Pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) or [Prospector](http://prospector.landscape.io/en/master/)).

And a few comments:

Use `os.path.join`:

```
self._path_A = os.path.join(self._base_directory, "A")
```

vs

```
self._path_A = self._base_directory + r"\A"
```

Consider using object methods to check for the content:

```
if not lines:
```

vs

```
if len(files) == 0:
```

Use the above mentioned tools to find obvious typos:

```
def print_files(self, heading, files):
```

vs

```
def print_files(sel, heading, files)
```

Do not name unused results:

```
for (dirpath, _, filenames) in os.walk(folder_path):
```

vs

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(folder_path):
```

You do not seem to take into account any subdirectories:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(folder_path):
   only_files.extend(filenames)
```

which you *might* want to do as you then try to remove files in them:

```
    for filepath in [os.path.join(self._path_A, file) for file in files_of_A_that_are_in_B]:
```

Wrap the top-level code into a function:

```
def main()
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        is_dry_run_argument = sys.argv[3]
        if not is_dry_run_argument == "--dryrun":
            print("The 3rd argument must be '--dryrun' or nothing.")
        else:
            app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=True)
    else:
        app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=False)
    app.delete_duplicates_in_folder_A()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

vs

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 4:
        is_dry_run_argument = sys.argv[3]
        if not is_dry_run_argument == "--dryrun":
            print("The 3rd argument must be '--dryrun' or nothing.")
        else:
            app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=True)
    else:
        app = DeleteDuplicateInFolderA(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2], is_dry_run=False)
    app.delete_duplicates_in_folder_A()
```

Answer (score 3):

To make things more Pythonic you should follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), as it is the standard for Pythonic code.

I personally would change `get_filenames_in_folder`, as it gets all child files, even ones in folders.
And so I'd make it a generator that yields files with paths relative to its folder.
I.e `.\spam.py` and `foo\bar.py`.
To achieve this you just need to add `os.path.relpath` and then `os.path.join` the result with the file name.
This results in:

```
def sub_files(folder):
    relpath = os.path.relpath
    join = os.path.join
    for path, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        relative = relpath(path, folder)
        for file in files:
            yield join(relative, file)
```

Your way of finding the `duplicates`, or as you call them `files_of_A_that_are_in_B`, is ok.
I'd go for an easier to read way of making sets and getting the unison. `set(files_a) & set(files_b)`.
Nice and easy to read.

I don't like that you print different things with and without `is_dry_run`.
Instead I'd make it print duplicates if there are some, otherwise nothing.
And I also don't like that any file that has the same name is a duplicate,
I can't think of good names when I want a temporary python file, and so I do make all: `tmp`, `temp`, `tmp.py`, `temp.py`.
Sometimes I even do `temp.temp.py`!
I know that those files are not duplicates, but have the same name.
So I'd use [`filecmp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html).

And so I'd use the following function to do the same as you:

```
def remove_duplicates(folder_a, folder_b, shallow=False, dry_run=False):
    folders = [folder_a, folder_b]
    files = [set(sub_files(folder)) for folder in folders]
    duplicates, *_ = groups = [files[0] & files[1]]
    if not shallow:
        duplicates, *_ = groups = filecmp.cmpfiles(*folders, duplicates)
    print('\n\n'.join(
        '{}:\n{}'.format(name, '\n'.join('    {}'.format(file) for file in files))
        for files, name in zip(groups, ('Duplicates', 'Non-Duplicates', 'Errors'))
        if files
    ))
    if not dry_run:
        join = os.path.join
        remove = os.remove
        for file in duplicates:
            remove(join(folder_a, file))
```

Which uses very little actual code.

After this, I'd change how do your `__main__`.
Instead of rolling your own argument passer, you can just use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).
Trust me it's really simple to make and use.
Instead of what you're doing, you can just do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('folder_a', help='folder to delete from')
    parser.add_argument('folder_b', help='folder to find duplicates in')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dry', help='dry-run the program', action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--shallow', help='only check file names for duplicates',
                        action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    remove_duplicates(args.folder_a, args.folder_b, shallow=args.shallow, dry_run=args.dry)
```

And you don't have to care about wrong input, as it'll never get to you.

The only thing that I think is ugly is the print I'm using, but since the alternate is slow or a lot longer I'm fine with it.
And possibly the `duplicates, *_` hack.
And so it could be:

```
import os
import filecmp
import argparse


def sub_files(folder):
    relpath = os.path.relpath
    join = os.path.join
    for path, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        relative = relpath(path, folder)
        for file in files:
            yield join(relative, file)


def remove_duplicates(folder_a, folder_b, shallow=False, dry_run=False):
    folders = [folder_a, folder_b]
    files = [set(sub_files(folder)) for folder in folders]
    duplicates, *_ = groups = [files[0] & files[1]]
    if not shallow:
        duplicates, *_ = groups = filecmp.cmpfiles(*folders, duplicates)
    print('\n\n'.join(
        '{}:\n{}'.format(name, '\n'.join('    {}'.format(file) for file in files))
        for files, name in zip(groups, ('Duplicates', 'Non-Duplicates', 'Errors'))
        if files
    ))
    if not dry_run:
        join = os.path.join
        remove = os.remove
        for file in duplicates:
            remove(join(folder_a, file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('folder_a', help='folder to delete from')
    parser.add_argument('folder_b', help='folder to find duplicates in')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dry', help='dry-run the program', action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--shallow', help='only check file names for duplicates',
                        action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    remove_duplicates(args.folder_a, args.folder_b, shallow=args.shallow, dry_run=args.dry)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first "duplicates" line should read

```
duplicates, *_ = groups  = [files[0] , files[1]]
```

my extended code

- move to trash - instead of delete

````
# Ferdiga
# moves duplicate files in folder_a to trash
# 20220625
# credits to
# https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133333/compare-files-by-name-in-two-folders-a-and-b-and-delete-duplicates-from-folder-a
import os
import filecmp
import argparse
from send2trash import send2trash

def sub_files(folder):
    relpath = os.path.relpath
    join = os.path.join
    for path, _, files in os.walk(folder):
        relative = relpath(path, folder)
        for file in files:
            yield join(relative, file)

def remove_duplicates(folder_a, folder_b, shallow=False, dry_run=False):
    Trash = "/Users/ferdinand/.Trash"
    folders = [folder_a, folder_b]
    files = [set(sub_files(folder)) for folder in folders]
    duplicates, *_ = groups  = [files[0] , files[1]]
    if not shallow:
        duplicates, *_ = groups = filecmp.cmpfiles(*folders, duplicates)
    print('\n\n'.join(
        '{}:\n{}'.format(name, '\n'.join('    {}'.format(file) for file in files))
        for files, name in zip(groups, ('Duplicates', 'Non-Duplicates', 'Errors'))
        if files
    ))
    if not dry_run:
        join = os.path.join
        for file in duplicates:
            send2trash(join(folder_a, file))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('folder_a', help='folder to delete from')
    parser.add_argument('folder_b', help='folder to find duplicates in')
    parser.add_argument('-d', '--dry', help='dry-run the program', action="store_true")
    parser.add_argument('-s', '--shallow', help='only check file names for duplicates',
                        action="store_true")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    remove_duplicates(args.folder_a, args.folder_b, shallow=args.shallow, dry_run=args.dry)

```
````